# BigQuery UDF works in one project but not another

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been using UDF's for a few months now with a lot of success.  Recently, I set up separate projects for development, and stream a sample of 1/10 of our web tracking data into these projects.

What I'm finding is that the UDF's I use in production, which operate on the full dataset, are working, while the exact same query in our development project consistently fails, despite querying 1/10 of the data.  The error message is:

> Query Failed
>
> Error: Resources exceeded during query execution: UDF out of memory.
>
> Error Location: User-defined function

I've looked through our Quotas and haven't found anything that would be limiting the development project.

Does anybody have any ideas?

If anybody can look into it, here are the project ids:

Successful query in production: bquijob_4af38ac9_155dc1160d9

Failed query in development: bquijob_536a2d2e_155dc153ed6

Comment: Hi, could you share the project ids for both projects?  I'm assuming that the jobs are running in different production cells for each project, and there's some sort of cell-specific issue going on.

Comment: @thomaspark i'm going to send you those directly via email

Comment: any updates @thomaspark?

Comment: Replied also via email  :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - solving via email

Comment: I'll document the solution here in case anybody else runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Jan-Karl, apologies for the late response; I've been out of the country to speak at some events in Japan and then have been dealing with oncall issues with production.

I finally got a chance to look into this for you.  The two job ids you sent me are running **very** different queries.  The queries *look* the same, but they're actually running over views, which have different definitions.  The query that succeeded is a straight `select * from table` whereas the one that has the JS OOM is using a UDF.

We're in the midst of rolling out a fix for the JS OOM issue, by allowing the JavaScript engine to use more RAM.

...

*...and now for some information that's not really relevant to this case, but that might be of future value...*

...

In theory, it could be possible for a query to succeed in one project and fail in another, even if they're running over **exactly the same dataset**.  This would be unusual, but possible.

Background : BigQuery operates and maintains copies of customer data in multiple datacentres for redundancy.  Different projects are biased to run in different datacentres to help with load spreading and utilisation.

A query will run in the default datacentre for its project if the data is fresh enough.  We have a process that replicates the data between datacentres, and we avoid running in a datacentre that has a stale copy of the data.  However, we run maintenance jobs to ensure that the files that comprise your data are of "optimal" size.  These jobs are scheduled separately per datacentre, so it's possible that your underlying data files for the same exact table would have a different physical structure in cell A and cell B.  It would be possible for this to affect aspects of a query's performance, and in extreme cases, a query may succeed in cell A but not B.